# postfix + dovecot configuration on receiving mail

Tags: debian, postfix, dovecot

I am trying to configure postfix+dovecot with SASL authentication on a debian squeeze server. I can send mail from the roundcube application but I cannot receive mail at all.

tail /var/log/mail.err reports this:

> dovecot: deliver(user@serverexample.com): userdb lookup: connect(/var/run/dovecot/auth-master) failed: No such file or directory

cat /mail.info | grep smtp

```
Jan  9 16:15:02 s1******** postfix/smtpd[11542]: connect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Jan  9 16:15:02 s1******** postfix/smtpd[11542]: lost connection after CONNECT from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Jan  9 16:15:02 s1******** postfix/smtpd[11542]: disconnect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Jan  9 16:20:01 s1******** postfix/smtpd[12715]: connect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Jan  9 16:20:01 s1******** postfix/smtpd[12715]: lost connection after CONNECT from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Jan  9 16:20:01 s1******** postfix/smtpd[12715]: disconnect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Jan  9 16:25:02 s1******** postfix/smtpd[13886]: connect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Jan  9 16:25:02 s1******** postfix/smtpd[13886]: lost connection after CONNECT from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Jan  9 16:25:02 s1******** postfix/smtpd[13886]: disconnect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Jan  9 16:30:01 s1******** postfix/smtpd[15048]: connect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Jan  9 16:30:01 s1******** postfix/smtpd[15048]: lost connection after CONNECT from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Jan  9 16:30:01 s1******** postfix/smtpd[15048]: disconnect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Jan  9 16:35:01 s1******** postfix/smtpd[16204]: connect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Jan  9 16:35:01 s1******** postfix/smtpd[16204]: lost connection after CONNECT from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Jan  9 16:35:01 s1******** postfix/smtpd[16204]: disconnect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Jan  9 16:40:02 s1******** postfix/smtpd[17370]: connect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Jan  9 16:40:02 s1******** postfix/smtpd[17370]: lost connection after CONNECT from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Jan  9 16:40:02 s1******** postfix/smtpd[17370]: disconnect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
```

cat /var/log/mail.err | grep smtp (notice that this is not happening since i changed some config files and restarted postfix):

```
Jan  9 14:36:03 s1******** postfix/smtpd[18443]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
Jan  9 14:36:03 s1******** postfix/smtpd[18444]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
Jan  9 14:40:02 s1******** postfix/smtpd[19368]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
Jan  9 14:44:32 s1******** postfix/smtpd[20446]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
Jan  9 14:45:33 s1******** postfix/smtpd[20710]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
Jan  9 14:48:35 s1******** postfix/smtpd[23032]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
Jan  9 14:50:01 s1******** postfix/smtpd[23357]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
```

cat /var/log/mail.err | grep postfix

```
Jan  9 16:39:07 s1******** postfix/qmgr[30385]: 4F95F4865: from=<my_user_name@gmail.com>, size=6283, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan  9 16:39:07 s1******** postfix/qmgr[30385]: D3EE14866: from=<my_user_name@gmail.com>, size=3030, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan  9 16:39:07 s1******** postfix/qmgr[30385]: CA3F34861: from=<my_user_name@gmail.com>, size=6308, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan  9 16:39:07 s1******** postfix/pipe[17148]: 4F95F4865: to=<user@serverexample.com>, relay=dovecot, delay=4631, delays=4631/0.08/0/0.05, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (temporary   failure)
Jan  9 16:39:07 s1******** postfix/pipe[17150]: D3EE14866: to=<user@serverexample.com>, relay=dovecot, delay=4523, delays=4523/0.06/0/0.03, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (temporary failure)
Jan  9 16:39:07 s1******** postfix/pipe[17148]: CA3F34861: to=<user@serverexample.com>, relay=dovecot, delay=4740, delays=4740/0.1/0/0.01, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (temporary failure)
Jan  9 16:40:02 s1******** postfix/smtpd[17370]: connect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Jan  9 16:40:02 s1******** postfix/smtpd[17370]: lost connection after CONNECT from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Jan  9 16:40:02 s1******** postfix/smtpd[17370]: disconnect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Jan  9 16:44:07 s1******** postfix/qmgr[30385]: EA65C485F: from=<SRS0=7kfH=LC=gmail.com=user+gmcfv372c65e7b3345f7@srs.kundenserver.de>, size=3856, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan  9 16:44:07 s1******** postfix/pipe[18291]: EA65C485F: to=<user@serverexample.com>, relay=dovecot, delay=5805, delays=5805/0.06/0/0.02, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (temporary failure)
Jan  9 16:45:01 s1******** postfix/pickup[30384]: B8D7F4869: uid=0 from=<root>
Jan  9 16:45:01 s1******** postfix/cleanup[18526]: B8D7F4869: message-id=<20130109154501.B8D7F4869@s1********.onlinehome-server.info>
Jan  9 16:45:01 s1******** postfix/qmgr[30385]: B8D7F4869: from=<root@s1********.onlinehome-server.info>, size=687, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan  9 16:45:01 s1******** postfix/smtpd[18531]: connect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Jan  9 16:45:01 s1******** postfix/smtpd[18531]: lost connection after CONNECT from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Jan  9 16:45:01 s1******** postfix/smtpd[18531]: disconnect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Jan  9 16:45:01 s1******** postfix/cleanup[18526]: EB0254867: message-id=<20130109154501.B8D7F4869@s1********.onlinehome-server.info>
Jan  9 16:45:01 s1******** postfix/qmgr[30385]: EB0254867: from=<root@s1********.onlinehome-server.info>, size=851, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan  9 16:45:01 s1******** postfix/local[18528]: B8D7F4869: to=<root@s1********.onlinehome-server.info>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=0.29, delays=0.12/0.1/0/0.07, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (forwarded as EB0254867)
Jan  9 16:45:01 s1******** postfix/qmgr[30385]: B8D7F4869: removed
Jan  9 16:45:02 s1******** postfix/smtp[18537]: connect to aspmx.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400c:c03::1b]:25: Network is unreachable
Jan  9 16:45:02 s1******** postfix/smtp[18537]: EB0254867: to=<hostmaster@serverexample.com>, orig_to=<root>, relay=aspmx.l.google.com[173.194.70.27]:25, delay=0.78, delays=0.01/0.06/0.27/0.44, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1357746302 l1si174424993een.25)
Jan  9 16:45:02 s1******** postfix/qmgr[30385]: EB0254867: removed
Jan  9 16:50:02 s1******** postfix/smtpd[19667]: connect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Jan  9 16:50:02 s1******** postfix/smtpd[19667]: lost connection after CONNECT from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Jan  9 16:50:02 s1******** postfix/smtpd[19667]: disconnect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Jan  9 16:55:01 s1******** postfix/smtpd[20814]: connect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Jan  9 16:55:01 s1******** postfix/smtpd[20814]: lost connection after CONNECT from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Jan  9 16:55:01 s1******** postfix/smtpd[20814]: disconnect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
```

Thanks

Comment: Receiving mail has nothing to do with your IMAP server. Mail is received through your SMTP server (postfix).

Comment: Who talked about imap !?

Comment: You did, in several places in your question. Specifically, the error you posted was emitted from dovecot.

Comment: ok, so i was mistaken.. if the problem is that i cannot receive mails from the outside world into my server email boxes, then the problem lies in smtp, right? what logs can i check ? thanks!

Comment: Postfix will log to `mail.log` and `mail.err` as well. What exactly happens when you send mail to your server? Is it even accepted by the server or does it reject it? If it accepts the mail, what does it do with it? You should be able to retrieve that information from `mail.log`.

Comment: When i send from my gmail account i do not receive any delivery problem reply.. it seems to send the email successfully, by the way i am running ispconfig 3 which is where i created the mailboxes, i will edit the answer with logs from mail.log

Comment: any clue in logs?